# jQuery request loads page, then 404 error code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code on my website. It loads the destination page for about 1 second before it reloads the div with a **404** error code. There is no jQuery requests on the destination pages.

```
<select name="Press_Type" id="Press_Type">
    <option value=0></option>
    <option value=0>Offset Press</option>
    <option value=1>Digital Press</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>

<div id="Press_Form_Devices_List">

</div>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#Press_Type").change(function() {

        var Press_Type_Value = jQuery("#Press_Type").val();

        jQuery("#Press_Form_Devices_List").load(Press_Type_Value);

        if (Press_Type_Value == "1") {
            jQuery("#Press_Form_Devices_List").load("add_digital.php");
        } else {
            if (Press_Type_Value == "0") {
                jQuery("#Press_Form_Devices_List").load("add_offset.php");
            }
        }

    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening is that your call to `jQuery("#Press_Form_Devices_List").load(Press_Type_Value);` loads "0" or "1" into the div, resulting in a 404 not found.

Then you load the "add_offset.php" or "add_digital.php" which works.

However, "add_offset.php" finishes loading first, then "0" or "1" throws a 404 error. This is why you see the one second delay before 404.

Try this code:

```
<select name="Press_Type" id="Press_Type">
    <option value=0></option>
    <option value=0>Offset Press</option>
    <option value=1>Digital Press</option>
</select>

<br><br>    

<div id="Press_Form_Devices_List">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery("#Press_Type").change( function() {

    var Press_Type_Value=jQuery("#Press_Type").val();

    if (Press_Type_Value=="1"){
        jQuery("#Press_Form_Devices_List").load("add_digital.php");
    } else if (Press_Type_Value=="0"){
        jQuery("#Press_Form_Devices_List").load("add_offset.php");
    }

})

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks like that worked. I had thrown that earlier piece of code in to try and debug something, but had forgotten that it might cause an error.

Comment: @DonSchlaich No problem!